# Get Records element not identifying related account of opportunity with varWhatID

Tags: visual-workflow

I am making a flow that updates a certain value in a picklist field on the related account of a task when it is marked complete.

The related to field can be either an account or an opportunity so I created a Decision element to determine if the WhatID is an account or opp, and then a Populate varWhatID Assignment element for the account result and a Get Records element that stores the varWhatID of the Account ID of the related to Opportunity ID for the opportunity result.

So far, it works with updating the accounts but I am not able to get the flow to correctly identify the opportunity. The debug error says it did not work because it "equals" 006 and should say "starts with" but I cannot get it to update to "starts with" even when changing the operator on the element.

During my testing I also found out that the flow clears out the picklist field of all existing fields to populate with the field identified in flow but I will tackle that problem separately.

debug log:

Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: Account
Outcome conditions

{!$Record__Prior.WhatId} (00602000007IYEsAAO) Starts with 001
All conditions must be true (AND)
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: Opportunity
Outcome conditions

{!$Record__Prior.WhatId} (00602000007IYEsAAO) Equals 006
All conditions must be true (AND)
Default outcome executed.
[image: full flow][image: first part of get records element][image: second part of get records element]

Comment: I'm not following -- the `Find_Opp` Get Records element should be using an `Equals` operator, not a `Starts With` operator when using `$Record>Related To Id`

Comment: @cropredy I changed the _Equals_ operator to _Starts With_ in an attempt to resolve the problem in the Debug log but I've changed it back to _Equals_. But the problem is still the same